# List of class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the equivalent of

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

in python?

if it does not exist, how to ensure that a list contains only instances of the class?

Comment: Only insert Person in list, create a wrapper that controls what you insert and throws ... but why would you? Python is not explicitly typed so you do not need to

Comment: There's type hinting, which probably bears more of a resemblance than you'd like - like Java generics, type hints are not checked at runtime.

Comment: Probably an overkill, but if you are desperate enough you can subclass `list` and override some methods.